# Duplicate policy created using same definition ID. How to avoid or list them

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Since more than one Azure policy assignment can use same Azure policy definition id, how can i avoid duplicacy or list out duplicate policy with same definition id.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Okay lets assume I have a client who assigned a particular policy manually from Azure Portal.   Now  other person is assigning it through a script(using Powershell or Terraform) in which one of the policies which he assigned is similar to the one which was assigned by client manually with same definition id. How  do avoid this, i do not want to check manually. Lets say the above scenario happened, how can i list out duplicate policy assigned (Duplication policy with same definition id)

Comment: Consider definition ID for example : 
  
 /providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/726671ac-c4de-4908-8c7d-6043ae62e3b6

Comment: Could someone check and help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure APIs provide ways to get all the policy assignments for a given policy definition

With [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/Get-AzPolicyAssignment?view=azps-2.4.0#parameters):

```
Get-AzPolicyAssignment
   -Id <String>
   [-PolicyDefinitionId <String>]
   [-ApiVersion <String>]
```

[REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/policyassignments/list#uri-parameters):

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments?$filter=policyDefinitionId eq '{policyDefinitionId}'&api-version=2018-05-01
```